# How to create fluid layout in modern HTML

Tags: html, layout, fluid-layout

I am quite a new to (or way too old for) a modern HTML, and i had to develop simple UI. I need to support 2 types of screen in it:

[image]

As may be seen above, my UI should consist of a menu, and content (for instance, a text with a picture aside or above). If displayed on a mobile in simple words it should be "rotated" 90 degrees CCW.

In my times layouts were done via `<table><tr><td>..` or `<frameset>..`-like stuff. But one scheme is `<td>item1</td><td>item2</td>` and the other is `<tr>item1</tr><tr>item2</tr>`. In a static .htm text file i can write only one variant. A way known to me is to make heavy use of javascript and generate a document via `document.write()`, but i dont quite like that idea, i believe something simplier should exist..

What is simpliest variant to do this in HTML manually, without using heavy and hard-to-learn frameworks?

Comment: Do you want to avoid CSS?

Comment: @ManojKumar No. CSS is good if it is possible to do with it. But how? I thought that CSS is the way to set page fonts and colors.. no? How could you rotate whole layout with it?

Comment: CSS is the best way to go. You can check out this: https://www.sitepoint.com/order-align-items-grid-layout/ along with the use of Media queries: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: If you can share some representative ([mcve]) code that you’re working with, and the relevant requirements, we can offer some approaches that might be of use, but we don’t link to, or write, broad tutorials.

Comment: @DavidThomas I shared such example with a picture of what i want to do. A menu a text and an image, and what should happen on a mobile screed. As for a code i have none yet. But someone kindly has pointed me to [menu in CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/)

Comment: Moved to specific exchange and got answer there: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/121718/how-to-switch-vertical-and-horisontal-layout-in-modern-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A basic structure with **flexbox** could be

(without any styling and dimension)

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
}

.list-unstyled {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767.99px) {
  .sm-fd-column {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .lg-fd-column {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  /* ... */
  .lg-order-2 {
    order: 2;
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex lg-fd-column">
  <div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled d-flex sm-fd-column">
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex sm-fd-column">
    <figure class="lg-order-2"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" alt=""></figure>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus saepe nobis impedit excepturi, perspiciatis! Eaque in quam corporis, modi, eos assumenda error totam autem cumque dolores magni deleniti! Doloribus, unde.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It provides two different sizes: small (sm) and large (lg).

More information about flexbox:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/